# Listen for changes in Redis?

Tags: node.js, redis

I want to be able to run a callback when any change is made in my redis collection. The callback would take the key and value as inputs. Is something like this possible?

Thanks?

Comment: Related Feature Request : https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/83

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can also connect to the Redis server like a follower using the sync command. See How [Redis Replication Works?](http://redis.io/topics/replication) for a quick introduction.

The output of sync command has two phases. In the first phase, the server returns the database dump.rdb file. Once the file is sent, it starts sending commands in the Redis protocol, which is also the AOF format.

Here is the high level picture of what you can do :

1. Connect to the Redis server and issue the `SYNC` command
2. Save and parse the dump.rdb file. Build the initial data set. A [node.js based rdb parser](https://github.com/pconstr/rdb-parser) is available
3. Parse the commands that follow. Since they are in Redis protocol, you can start with an existing Redis library.
4. For every command you receive, invoke a callback

It seems a lot of work, but you should be able to hack this pretty easily. And it would make a good open source library too!

**EDIT : Sync v/s Monitor**

1. `Monitor` is a debugging command. The response format can (and has) change(d) over time. `Sync` is used for Master -> Slave replication, and so will be better supported
2. `Monitor` will emit all commands, including read-only commands. `Sync` will only get you commands that modify data.
3. `Monitor` will log individual commands that are executed within a lua script. `Sync` will only transfer the entire lua script, so you will have to parse the script yourself. This is indeed a deal breaker for `sync`.
4. `Monitor` will log commands that did not succeed, `Sync` will only log commands that modify data. For example, the command `del non-existing-key` will be logged by monitor but won't show up when you run sync.

Comment: Thanks Sripathi! Could you give me a high-level overview of this vs using monitor for updates?

Answer (score 34):

**UPDATE (2020)**: Whomever is reading this - these are ancient answers, **disregard them all**. What you need is Redis Keyspace Notifications which have been around for ages. See https://redis.io/topics/notifications

Answer (score 18):

Two options:

1. Use [`MONITOR`](http://redis.io/commands/monitor) command - it traces every command that gets to Redis and you can analyze and see when your collection is being touched.
2. If you "own" the code that writes to the collection, signal your other code (your callback). You can use [Redis Pub/Sub](http://redis.io/topics/pubsub) channel for this.

**EDIT** Redis is actually going to implement this feature in version 2.8. See Antirez's blog post on this: [Redis keyspace changes notification system](https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/594).

Comment: And `MONITOR` reduces the [performance by more than half](https://redis.io/commands/monitor), so you better not run that in Production very often

Answer (score 5):

**In 2017**

There's now a publish/subscribe mechanism which you can use with `node-redis` module. See specific documentation [HERE](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis#publish--subscribe). (Also works with `redis-mock` for testing)

You can have several subscribers (listeners) to the same channel, which in your case would be the key to your collection.

quick sample: (see above documentation for implementation details)

```
sub.subscribe('myCollection');
sub.on('message', (channel, data) => {
    // this is the callback you talked about
    console.log(`${channel} is now ${data}`);
});

// ... later on ...

pub.publish('myCollection', [1,2,3])
// console will output:
// myCollection is now [1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.moilioncircle</groupId>
    <artifactId>redis-replicator</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

If you are using java. `redis-replicator` implements redis replication protocol.
More details please refer to [references](https://github.com/leonchen83/redis-replicator)